# Is it correct to use straight connections to microservices parallel to a BFF pattern?

Tags: architecture, frontend, microservices, gateway, api-gateway

BFF - Back For Front pattern.
BFF pattern means that we have API gateway for each client.
BFF at this point can be a bottleneck for some microservices.

1. Can single client has multiple BFFs (gateways) ?
2. If we have one of the client that has BFF, but also have straight connection to some additional microservices for that client.. is it correct to call BFF as `BFF` or it is just some gateway or something else entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, a backend for front end is a layer between front ends and microservices designed to serve the data as the specific front end requires. So it should be designed with the front end needs in mind.

Because of this, this backend should have endpoints for all the data needed for the front end and with the format required by the front end. So it has the responsibility to call whatever microservices are required to aggregate the data.

Having this in mind I think it doesn't make sense that the frontend uses two different BFF or other endpoints not provided by its specific BFF

Comment: There is only one problem that I see - BFF will become a bottleneck, it will pass all queries through themself, and I think this can be a problem in future. So my point is to work with some complex microservices without BFF as gateway.

Comment: Because BFF is intended to be a gateway as you say without state, you can scale it with the number of instances you need to satisfy the traffic demand